# Java - while loop for scanner validation results in failed input

Tags: java, class, intellij-idea, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I am trying to add the following scanner validation as follows;

```
public void promptFilmRating() {
    while (!filmScanner.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number instead of text.");
        filmScanner.next();
    }
    while (filmScanner.nextInt() > 5 || filmScanner.nextInt() < 1) {
        System.out.println("Your number is outside of the rating boundaries, enter a number between 1 and 5.");
        filmRatingOutOfFive = filmScanner.nextInt();
    }

}
```

However when using the code that relates to the integer between value validation, repeated inputs are needed in order to record the original input and I am unsure on how to correct this, any advice would be fantastic.

Comment: store it into a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Store the value that you are getting in a variable, and use that variable to perform the checks.

Here is an example:

```
private void promptFilmRating() {

    Scanner filmScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int filmRatingOutOfFive;

    do{
        System.out.println("Please enter your rating for the film:");
        filmRatingOutOfFive = filmScanner.nextInt();

        if(filmRatingOutOfFive > 5 || filmRatingOutOfFive < 1)
            System.out.println("Your number is outside of the rating boundaries, enter a number between 1 and 5.");

    }while(filmRatingOutOfFive > 5 || filmRatingOutOfFive < 1);


    System.out.println("You rated this film: "+filmRatingOutOfFive+" out of 5");


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is in `while (filmScanner.nextInt() > 5 || filmScanner.nextInt() < 1) {`. 
Every call to `filmScanner.nextInt()` asks the stream for a new integer, so by calling `.nextInt()` twice in the while statement, you are asking for two numbers.

You might want to consider combining your two loops into one. 
Example:

```
int myNum;
do {
    myNumb = filmScanner.nextInt();
} while (myNum > 5 || myNum < 1);
```